# A comparision between two subadditivity

Tags: real-analysis

I have a simple question about the subadditivity of inf,
it's easy to show that

$\inf_x (f+g)(x) \ge \inf_x f(x) + \inf_y g(y)$.

And for norm we have

$\inf_{x\in X,y\in Y}(\|x\|+\|y\|)\le \inf_{x\in X}\|x\| +\inf_{y\in Y}\|y\|$.

My qustion is why they look quite similar but with different directions of inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second done is actually an equality. The first one would have been an equality if we had $\inf_{x,y} (f(x)+g(y))$ instead of $\inf_x (f+g)(x))$. The main difference is you have two variables $x$ and independent of each other in the second one whereas there is only one variable in the LHS of first inequality.

Comment: For the second inequality if we further impose space $X$ is somewhat correlated with $Y$, does the equality still hold?For example assume all are vector space define $S\subset W$ with $X = x+S$ and $Y = y+S$.If not does the second inequality still holds?

Comment: No. $x$ and $y$ have to vary independently for the second in equality to hold.

Comment: What's wrong with my proof,for the reverse direction as follows, since for any $x,y$, inequality $\|x\| + \|y\| \ge \inf \|x\| + \inf\|y\|$ holds,if we take $\inf$ on LHS we have $\inf (\|x\|+\|y\|)\ge \inf \|x\| + \inf\|y\| $

Comment: As I said in the first line of my answer the second inequality is actually an equality. Te reverse inequality always holds. Your argument for the reverse inequality is correct.

Comment: I got it thanks